# Proof that Zsigmondy Numbers are the Maximal Overpseudoprimes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It is stated in https://oeis.org/A064078 that Zsigmondy numbers, Z, are the maximal overpseudoprimes base 2 that divide $2^n-1$, where n is the multiplicative order of 2 modulo Z ($2^n-1\equiv 0\mod Z$).
However, I could not find a proof of this online. Zsigmondy numbers can also be thought of as the product of all of the primitive prime divisors of $2^n-1$ as they are coprime to all the previous terms. My questions are:

(1)What is a proof that they are the overpseudoprimes? 
(2)Are there any other properties of Zsigmondy numbers? 
(3)Additionally, is this generalizable for base k?

Any answers would be much appreciated as I cannot find many resources online.

Comment: It is stated **where**? Provide your source, there may be important contextual clues. Also, talking about things which you acknowledge are hard to find online without defining them also leaves readers in the lurch about what you are talking about. I recommend you backfill some of these gaps by editing your question. Otherwise readers will probably not deign it a good use of time to spend time answering.

Comment: The link was previously provided in parentheses. I will try to edit my question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Could you add a definition of "overpseudoprimes" ?